people API with syncToken returns contacts that are not changed
When I request only changed contacts using the People API and a syncToken, Google returns many contacts that have no changed data.
I believe the problem is not with the API itself, but rather that google marks a contact as change/updated when no new values have been saved to the contact itself -- e.g. when you email or call that person on your device, etc, etc. But I even see some contacts returned by the call when I haven't emailed or spoken to that person in years.
Does anyone know how to defeat this, or work around it? or is there some other method in the API that will only return contacts that actually have new data?
Is there any discussion from Google on how/why this happens, or acknowledgement that it's a bug and they might someday fix it?
API reference page:
https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts#list_the_users_contacts_that_have_changed

What programming language did you use? Is it the sample Java code in the article on your post?

Hi @serenity, I think it's irrelevant, but I'm using Google Apps Script (javascript)

I'm trying to replicate your issue. That's why I asked if you are using the sample Java code in the article you have shared. Could you provide the code you're using?

OH I get it. Yeah the sample code will work fine.
